# Duvida calcular média com Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou criando um programa, utilizando Python 3.5, para calcular média, mas na minha escola há algumas matérias com dois professores, e cada um da uma prova diferente.

O problema é que o código que criei faz a media de `(Prova 1 + Prova 2)/2`, que é igual a `media1`, `(Atividade 1 + Atividade 2)/2`, que é igual a média 2, e a média final é com o Simulado `(media1+media2+simulado)/3`, e quando é uma matéria não coloco nada na P2 dá erro. Eu estava pensando, quando o usuário inserir o nome da matéria executar tal código, e outro nome, outro código, como faço isso?

Meu código:

```
nota1 = float(input("Nota1: "))

nota2 = float(input('Nota 2: '))

simulado = float(input('Nota simulado: '))

ac1 = float(input('Nota AC1: '))

ac2 = float(input('Nota AC2: '))


media1 = (nota1+nota2)/2
mediaAC = (ac1+ac2)/2
mediaf = (media1+simulado+mediaAC)/3 

print (mediaf)

if mediaf == 6:
   print("na media")


if mediaf < 6:
   print("abaixo da media")
```

Comment: Olá @gust4vo, você poderia colocar o código que você já construiu e o que você já tentou na sua pergunta?

Comment: pronto, inseri o codigo.

Comment: Qual erro você está obtendo? Detalhe um pouco mais...

Comment: Não é um erro, eu queria saber como faço para quando, por exemplo, uma variavel for igual a Matematica, um determinado código é executado(se matemática tem 2 provas, o código com média para duas matérias é executado), e caso for uma matéria com uma prova, o código dessa média é executado. Tentei deixar o espaço da P2 em branco, mas o erro foi esse: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gusta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\notateste.py", line 2, in <module>
    nota2 = float(input('Nota 2: '))
ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: @gust4vo, muda o titulo com um resumo da sua duvida, para outros usuarios identificar sua duvida e poder te ajudar também. Abracos!

Answer (score 2):

```
from functools import partial

notas = list(map(float,list(iter(partial(input, 'Nota: '), ''))))
ac = list(map(float,list(iter(partial(input, 'AC: '), ''))))
simulado = float(input('Nota simulado: '))

media_notas = sum(notas)/len(notas)
media_ac = sum(ac)/len(ac)
media_final = (media_notas + media_ac + simulado) / 3 


print('medias: ', media_notas, media_ac, media_final)

if media_final >= 6:
    print('na media')
else:
    print('abaixo da media')
```

Dessa maneira tu digitas quantas notas forem necessárias, até o valor da nota ser vazio (digitar 'Enter'). Exemplo:

```
$ python notas.py 
Nota: 5
Nota: 10
Nota: 
AC: 5
AC: 5
AC: 
Nota simulado: 10
notas:  7.5 5.0 7.5
na media
```

Comment: Olá, o código deu erro.

Comment: Qual erro? Estás usando qual versão do Python? Testei novamente aqui e funcionou. Uso python2.7

Comment: Antes de mais nada, um dos problemas do seu código é o `print`, pois em Python 3 precisa de parenteses: `print('abaixo da media')`

Comment: @GuilhermeIA Quando eu respondi a pergunta não estava escrito a versão do python. O título, texto e TAG foram adicionados nas edições. Editei a resposta para executar no python 3.5

Answer (score 1):

Opa! Cara, sou iniciante mas tentei implementar uma solução para você:

```
qtd_notas = int(input("Digite a quantidade de notas: "))
notas = 0
for i in range(0, qtd_notas):
    notas += input("Digite a nota " + str(i + 1) + ": ")

media = notas / qtd_notas

simulado = input("Nota Simulado: ")

acs = 0

for i in range(0, qtd_notas):
    acs += input("Notas AC" + str(i + 1) + ": ")

media_ac = acs/qtd_notas

media_final = (media + simulado + media_ac) / 3

print (media_final)

if media_final == 6:
    print ("na media")
if media_final < 6:
    print ("abaixo da media")
```

O que eu fiz foi colocar para, no início, o usuário digitar a quantidade de notas que irão compor as médias. Ignore as variáveis.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Olá, não consegui executar o código, deu erro: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/gusta/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32/teste.py", line 3, in <module>
    for i in range(0, qtd_notas):
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: Opa! Editei o código, adicionei uma conversão para int em qtd_notas. Espero que agora dê! rsrs

Answer (score 0):

Outra forma de se resolver a questão é a seguinte:

```
notas = list(map(float, input('Digite as notas das provas: ').split()))
ac = list(map(float, input('Digite as notas das atividades: ').split()))
simulado = float(input('Digite a nota do simulado: '))

media_provas = (sum(notas) / len(notas))
media_ac = (sum(ac) / len(ac))
media_final = ((media_provas + media_ac + simulado) / 3)

print(f'\033[32mA Média Final é: {media_final:.1f}')

if media_final >= 6:
    print('Na média!')
else:
    print('Abaixo da média')
```

Quando executamos o algoritmo recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Digite a nota das provas:`. Neste momento devemos digitar **todas** as notas das provas, na **mesma** linha, **separados** por um só espaço e pressionar `enter`. Em seguida, recebemos a seguinte mensagem `Digite as notas das atividades:`. Neste momento devemos digitar **todas** as notas das atividades, na **mesma** linha, **separados** por um só espaço e pressionar `enter`. Em seguida recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Digite a nota do simulado:`. Neste momento devemos digitar a nota do simulado e pressionar `enter`.

Depois de ter inserido todas as notas o algoritmo irá realizar o cálculo das médias, exibindo apenas a `média final` e a `situação` do aluno.

Answer (score -2):

```
from functools import partial

notas = list(map(float,list(iter(partial(input, 'Nota: '), ''))))

media_notas = sum(notas)/len(notas)


print(f'media: {media_notas:.2f}')

if media_notas == 6:

print('na media')
elif media_notas > 6:
print('acima da media')
else:
print('abaixo da media')
```

Answer (score -6):

Tá aqui o que eu fiz, ta bem simplezinho mas serve.

```
     pn=float(input('Digite sua primeira nota: '))

     sn=float(input('Digite sua segunda nota: '))

     m=(pn+sn)/2

     if m<6.00:
         print('Você não passou com {} de média'.format(m))
     if m>=6.00:
         print('Você passou com {} de média'.format(m))
```